# Displaying audit history in hibernate envers

Tags: hibernate-envers

I am new to hibernate envers.I have successfully created audit tables for each entities.but i don know how to read these history for each entity.I want to display this history in a jsp.I want to read all the history for that particular entity.any body know how it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the AuditReader class:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html

And the Envers tutorial:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html/ch05.html